# Doesn't CMIS 1.1 work with Alfresco 5.0.d?

Tags: alfresco, opencmis

I am trying to connect to an Alfresco 5.0.d Repository via CMIS 1.1 (apache chemistry 0.13) to read some data and create some objects, but I get exceptions in the repo.

- when I try to run a CQL query I get a NPE in `org.alfresco.opencmis.CMISNodeInfoImpl:441`
- when I try to create an object I get a NPE in `org.alfresco.opencmis.mapping.SecondaryTypesProperty:44`

In both cases it looks like the CMISConnector object is not fully initialized. All referenced beans are `null`. Is this a bug in Alfresco 5.0.d or have I missed some config ?

When I do the same against an Alfresco 5.0.c repository, it works fine. That's why I am not attaching any code.

Comment: What is the endpoint you are connected to ?

Comment: Of course there's always the most important things one forgets. I connect to http://localhost:8080/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.1/atom

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I had a funny Spring configuration that the CMISConnector instantiate 50+ times, but only one of those instances was complete.